# MySQL: как вернуть самое максимально значение поля из таблицы?

Tags: php, mysql

самый простой пример если можно приведите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$row = mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query("select max(`field`) as `myname_of_var` from `table`"));

print($row->myname_of_var);
```

А вообще, фреймворки юзайте

Answer (score 1):

```
select max(`field`) from `table`
```

**upd**

```
$db=new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$req=$db->prepare("select max(`field`) from `table`");
$req->execute();
$max=current($req->fetch());
echo '$max=',$max;
```

Comment: это я и так знаю, дальше как это все в php записать? чтобы я четко видел что переменная $max получила значение максимальное.

Answer (score 1):

```
   MAX ()  -
```

[документация](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max)

Comment: дальше что?

Comment: дальше читайте как зафетчит выбранное значение с базы